# moving python lxml module to a remote directory

Tags: python, lxml, python-2.6

I've just spent an hour looking this up and I can't seem to find the answer.
I'm running a number of windows workstations and a few linux servers. To keep python module machine installs at a minimum, I'm installing new modules to my machine, then looking at the install log and copying the files to a location on a server.  Every machine sees the server location and the environments and paths are set up and this has been working fine for months.

I just installed lxml and copied the site-packages/lxml directory to the server.

The local install works, the server install doesn't. I get:

> from lxml import etree

```
# Error: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. #
```

I grepped the local python26 directory for all 'lxml' files and I'm not coming up with anything I haven't copied over.  versions= python 2.6.6  lxml-3.2.3.win-amd64-py2.6
Anyone have any thoughts?  How come I haven't seen this issue with other modules?

thanks smart people!

Comment: Are you trying to use your windows python libraries on a linux machine?

Comment: No, just access them. All of our workstations are windows 7, Linux is just used for the servers, and we don't use the linux machines for processing.

Answer (score 0):

Because the lxml use the c extension (they are dll files on windows or .so files on unix/linux after compiled), you can not make it works just copy the files which builded on the windows to the server simplely.

And you can download the source code of lxml in [lxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml),
And the run

`python setup install`
under the lxml root dir in the server.

Or maybe you can build local and then upload the builded files to the server, just run 
`python setup.py build`
under the lxml root dir in the local, and then copy the ./build/*/lxml to the server!
But it may not works as it is platform related!

Comment: anyone know the location of the DLL files?

Comment: The c extension if the .so or .a file in linux while DLL file in windows.(An .so file is a compiled library file. It stands for "Shared Object" and is analogous to a Windows DLL.) So need compiled the lxml in the linux but not copy the DLL files in windows to the linux server.